# Use REPLACE in multicondition RegExp in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have this set of data:

```
dump data;
```

This is a sample output: (this dataset is almost a million rows long).

```
("0",60,0,1,"Fri")
("1",47,0,1,"Mon")
("1",23,1,0,"Tue")
("1",60,0,0,"Sat")
("1",50,1,1,"Fri")
```

I want to replace the values: Sat, Fri, Mon to numbers of week, I know how to use REPLACE for change just 1 value at a time, but I have to repeat it multiple times in order to change all days of the week:

```
data_day_of_week = FOREACH data GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,REPLACE($4, 'Mon', '1');
```

Is there any way to do this in only one statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

saph_top, was the closer one to answer my question, nonetheless after testing it was resolving blank output, I'm going to complement his answer:

'Mon' is not the same as "Mon", therefore when I was using: CASE WHEN $4 == 'Mon' THEN '1' It wasn´t replacing anything, resulting in blank result in: data_day_of_week.

To solve this, I just add " " (double quotes to the condition):

```
data_day_of_week = FOREACH data GENERATE
CASE
     WHEN $4 == '"Mon"' THEN '1'
     WHEN $4 == '"Tue"' THEN '2'
     ...
     WHEN $4 == '"Sun"' THEN '7'
END AS day_number;
```

After that in order to rebuild the data I add the following to GENERATE Clause:

```
data_day_of_week = FOREACH data GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,
    CASE
         WHEN $4 == '"Mon"' THEN '1'
         WHEN $4 == '"Tue"' THEN '2'
         ...
         WHEN $4 == '"Sun"' THEN '7'
    END AS day_number;
```

And the output was complete now:
dump data_day_of_week;

```
("0",60,0,1,5)
("1",47,0,1,1)
("1",23,1,0,2)
("1",60,0,0,6)
("1",50,1,1,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the Pig ToDate and ToString functions:

```
data_day_of_week = FOREACH data GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,
    ToString(ToDate($4, 'EEE'), 'e') as day_of_week;
```

The [ToDate](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/ToDate.html) functions will convert the chararray day of the week to a Pig date time format. Then [ToString](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/ToString.html) will convert this to a format of your choosing.

According to the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) a single e or c should give the numeric format for the day of the week, where Monday is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a CASE WHEN THEN statement

```
data_day_of_week = FOREACH data GENERATE
    CASE
         WHEN $4 == 'Mon' THEN '1'
         WHEN $4 == 'Tue' THEN '2'
         ...
         WHEN $4 == 'Sun' THEN '7'
    END AS day_number;
```

You should also name your relations so not to use $1, $2 etc. If you name $4 as day_number then when you declare the variable as day_number from the CASE statement it'll "overwrite" your prior data.

Comment: Thank you saph_top, but when I try this method, it results in blank result:  [for the sake of the comment I just keep the end of your query]END AS day_number , $0, $1,$2,$3; It does bring the other relations but, day_number wont appear, it shows something like: 
("1",50,1,1,) the place were should be populated by day_number just doesn't show's up. I've tried naming all the relations, but the result is the same.

Comment: I've try your Query to replace numbers, in this case it works but in chararray it won't

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN with a reference to a mapping like this:

```
(Mon,1)
(Tue,2)
(Wed,3)
(Thu,4)
(Fri,5)
(Sat,6)
(Sun,7)
```

Join statement:

```
outer_left = join your_data by $4 left outer, day_mapping by day;
```